# Hive - Beeline - how to pass exceptions from fileinputformat to beeline

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, beeline

My FileInputFormat throws exception sometimes, and I'd like the user to see the message from the exception.  Is there a way to inform beeline of the exception.  It just shows `Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask (state=08S01,code=1)`

Comment: I can't test right now but you might try adding `--verbose=true` and `--showNestedErrs=true` to your beeline call.

Comment: @JeremyBeard, thank you!  I see the exception now, but not the nested exception...

Comment: Ok, I will add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beeline will provide more error messages if you add the `--verbose=true` and `--showNestedErrs=true` flags to your `beeline` call.